# Javascript replace email addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

quick question - Why isn't this working?

I'm pretty sure that I've tested everything to no avail. I'm trying to basically add mailto links to any email that can be found.

It's not replacing the email links with the mailto a tags.

Thanks,
Harry

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email_regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi;

    var bodyText = $('body').html();
    var match = email_regex.exec(bodyText);
    // To do - Don't try it when there is already a mailto link, can probably just add mailto to the regex.
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        bodyText.replace(match[i], '<a href="mailto:' + match[i] + '">' + match[i] + '</a>');
        console.log(match[i]);
    }
    $('body').html(bodyText);
    console.dir(match);
});
```

Comment: Hey Harry, what isn't working?

Comment: I've updated the OP - It's not replacing the email links with the mailto a tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the `g` flag does not retrieve all matches at once. It merely allows to call `exec()` in a loop. You'd need:

```
var match;
while ( (match = email_regex.exec(bodyText)) !==null) {
}
```

The second problem is that `replace()` does not modify the original string. You'd need:

```
bodyText= bodyText.replace(match[i], '<a href="mailto:' + match[i] + '">' + match[i] + '</a>');
```

Still, you could easily get into an infinite loop this way. You'd need to work on a copy:

```
var newBodyText = bodyText;
...
while ( (match = email_regex.exec(bodyText)) !==null) {
    ...
    newBodyText = newBodyText.replace(...)
}
$('body').html(newBodyText);
```

Reference:

- [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Answer (score 11):

You should instead to this I suppose:

```
 var result = bodyText.replace(email_regex,'<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
 console.log(result); // This two lines are enough.
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email_regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi;
    var bodyText = $('body').html();
    var result = bodyText.replace(email_regex,'<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
    console.log(result); // This two lines are enough.
});
```

Comment: glad to have helped ;)

Comment: +1 though, technically speaking, this doesn't answer the *Why isn't this working* question ;-)

Comment: This regexp does not work well, a text that include a dot after the mail will include the dot in the link, this work better: `/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)(?<!\.)/gi`